# How to get device specification ( ram - storage - cpu ) library or api Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity

i need get Android device specification ( ram - storage - cpu - resolution ) , is that there is exist an API or library ???, thanks you for help

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html

Answer (score 0):

```
public void getCpuInfo() {
    try {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat /proc/cpuinfo");
        InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvcmd);
        tv.setText(getStringFromInputStream(is));
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "------ getCpuInfo " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void getMemoryInfo() {
    try {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat /proc/meminfo");
        InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvcmd);
        tv.setText(getStringFromInputStream(is));
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "------ getMemoryInfo " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

private static String getStringFromInputStream(InputStream is) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line = null;

    try {
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append("\n");
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "------ getStringFromInputStream " + e.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        if(br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "------ getStringFromInputStream " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }       

    return sb.toString();
}
```

If you want the display dimensions in pixels you can use getSize:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

This method was introduced in Android API 13, so if you want to get display metrics for previous APIs use:

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int wwidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

If you're not in an Activity, you can get the default Display via WINDOW_SERVICE. Also be sure to set your minSdkVersion to at least 4 in AndroidManifest.xml to enable calls to display.getWidth().

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth();  // deprecated
int height = display.getHeight();
```

Hope it will help you.I don't know of any library or api.

Comment: ok :) thank you , for la resolution i dont know why dont display exactly 1776 * 1080 instead of 1900 * 1080

Comment: Can you tell me what sdk version are you using.If this answer helps you please accept it to help others.